# Big Query Record split into multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like:

```
text           |  STRING
concepts       |  RECORD
concepts.name  |  STRING
[...]
```

So one row could look like this:

```
"This is a text about BigQuery and how to split records into columns. "
SQL
BigQuery
Questions
```

I would like to transform that into:

```
text, concepts_1, concepts_2, concepts_3 // The names are not important
"This is a text about BigQuery and how to split records into columns. ",SQL,BigQuery,Questions
```

The number of concepts in each row vary.

EDIT:

This would also work:

```
text, concepts
"This is a text about BigQuery and how to split records into columns. ","SQL,BigQuery,Questions"
```

Comment: Have you tried using [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest)? Could you clarify if you only want to retrieve the values from the RECORD column, or if you want to create a new table based on that RECORD column?

Comment: Unnest will only help me to create:

"This is a text about BigQuery and how to split records into columns. ", SQL
"This is a text about BigQuery and how to split records into columns. ", BigQuery
"This is a text about BigQuery and how to split records into columns. ", Questions

I just want to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

If comma separated list is fine with you - consider below shortcut versions

```
#standardSQL
SELECT identifier, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ', ') FROM UNNEST(concepts)) AS conceptName
FROM `project.dataset.articles`
```

and

```
#standardSQL
SELECT identifier, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ', ') FROM articles.concepts) AS conceptName
FROM `project.dataset.articles` articles
```

Both above versions return output like below

```
Row identifier  conceptName  
1   1           SQL, BigQuery, Questions     
2   2           xxx, yyy, zzz
```

As you can see - above versions are brief and compact and don't use extra grouping to array with then transforming it into string - as all this can be done in one simple shot

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me. But it only creates a comma-separated string. However, in my case, this was fine.

```
SELECT articles.identifier, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(concepts.name), ",") as 
conceptName
FROM `` articles, UNNEST(concepts) concepts
GROUP BY articles.identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
SELECT
  text,
  c.*
FROM
  `your_project.your_dataset.your_table`,
  UNNEST(
  concepts
    ) c
```

This will get the text column along with the unnested values from your RECORD column.

Hope it helps.